# Using a button in a extend blade to trigger a modal doesn't work (blade laravel)

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to trigger a modal that would allow me to confirm the deletion of a user from my backoffice, the problem is that when I test on a page like welcome.blade.php (not nested) it works.
but when I test on a page I extended from a layout it doesn't work

**Utilisateurs/index.blade.php**

```html
@extends('Layout.index')

@section('style')

@endsection

@section('title')
    index | Utilisateurs
@endsection

@section('titleSectionH2')
    d'Utilisateurs
@endsection

@section('addButtonH2')
    un Utilisateur
@endsection

@section('indexSearchPlaceholder')
    Utilisateurs
@endsection

@section('addButtonLink')
    {{ route('adminUserCreate') }}
@endsection

@section('tableHeader')
    <th class="align-middle">ID</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Avatar</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Pseudo</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Nom et Prénom</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Age</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Email</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Date D'Inscription</th>
    <th class="align-middle">Actions</th>
@endsection

@section('tableData')
    @foreach($users as $user)
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->id }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">
                <img src="{{ asset( 'storage/' . $user->avatar ) }}" height="50" width="50">
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->pseudo }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->lastName }} {{ $user->firstName }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->age }} ans</td>
            <td class="align-middle" style="max-width: 14vw; overflow: scroll; overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;">{{ $user->email }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle" style="min-width: 12vw">
                <a href="{{ route('adminUserShow' , $user->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1">Voir Plus</button></a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
                    Supprimer
                </button>
{{--                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exempleModalCenter">Supprimer</button>--}}
{{--                <a href="{{ route('adminUserDestroy' , $user->id) }}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">Supprimer</button></a>--}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
@endsection

@section('indexModal')
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

@section('paginate')
    {{ $users->links() }}
@endsection
```

**Layout/index.blade.php**

```html
@extends('Layout.master')

@section('style')
{{--    <style>--}}
        .add_Button {
            margin-bottom: 2px;
        }
{{--    </style>--}}
@endsection

@section('content')
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="{{ asset('images/laravelLogo.png') }}" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
                Remediation Thomas | Administration
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('homepage') }}">Accueil<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Administration
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('adminUserIndex') }}">Utilisateurs</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Livres</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Auteurs</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Genres</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Téléchargement<span class="sr-only"></span></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav ml-auto" action="{{ route('adminUserSearch') }}" method="GET">
                        @csrf
                        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="@yield('indexSearchPlaceholder')" aria-label="Search" name="Search">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><img width="20" src="{{ asset('icons/search-24px.svg') }}"></button>
                    </form>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <section class="row mx-1 mt-1">
            <h2><b>Liste @yield('titleSectionH2')</b></h2>
            <a class="ml-auto" href=@yield('addButtonLink')><button class="btn"><img class="add_Button" src="{{ asset('icons/add-24px.svg') }}" alt="add"> Ajouter @yield('addButtonH2')</button></a>
        </section>
        @if(session()->has('info'))
            <section class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                {{session('info')}}
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </section>
        @endif
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover shadow text-center mx-auto">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @yield('tableHeader')
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    @yield('tableData')
    {{--                <td></td>--}}
    {{--                <td>--}}
    {{--                    <a href="{{route('editUser', $item->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-info m-1">MODIFIER</button></a>--}}
    {{--                    <a href="{{route('destroyUser', $item->id)}}"><button class="btn btn-outline-danger">SUPPRIMER</button></a>--}}
    {{--                </td>--}}
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <section>
            @yield('paginate')
        </section>
        @yield('indexModal')
    </main>
    <script>
        $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
        })
    </script>
    @endsection
```

I tried to put the scripts in my layout or directly in the html code of my blade "**Utilisateurs/index**" but nothing to do it doesn't trigger

Comment: did you place any Javascript tag in the page you extended ?, lus can you also share the code of the page you extended.

Comment: When I say js that's what I put in my script tag I don't know if it's js actually ^^'
but I just put it in the layout or pasted it directly into the modal code. 
`$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
            $('#myInput').trigger('focus')
        })`

Comment: ok I found it was enough to put the modal at the top of my page in the layout